# TypeScript: Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & Element'. Why it doesn't exist?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I receive this error

> Error:(17, 35) TS2339: Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & Element'.

But that's definitely impossible error because React docs says `checked` does exist on `target` of checkbox (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs)

[image]

Here is my code. What's wrong with it so TS blows up?

```js
// I specify a type for event. It must have `checked` property.
  onToggle = (ev: React.ChangeEvent) => {
    console.log('[ev]', ev.target.checked); // <= TS throws here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="switch" id="switch" onChange={ev => this.onToggle(ev)} checked={this.state.on}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

**Alternative error message:**

> TS2339: Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Answer (score 20):

Here is a fix. You have to specify type of the element of `ChangeEvent`

```js
  onToggle = (ev: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  // onToggle = (ev: React.ChangeEvent) => {
    console.log('[ev]', ev.target.checked); // <= TS throws here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="switch" id="switch" onChange={ev => this.onToggle(ev)} checked={this.state.on}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: alternatively `ev.target['checked']` to bypass the property check...

Answer (score 5):

Check out this, I currently apply this way to my project.

```js
  onToggle = (ev: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log('[ev]', (ev.target as HTMLInputElement).checked);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="switch" id="switch" onChange={onToggle} checked={this.state.on}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Btw, I think you should try `useState` for getting/setting the state of the `checked` value. For example:

```js
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)

const onToggle = (ev: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setChecked((ev.target as HTMLInputElement).checked);
    };

...

 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="switch" id="switch" onChange={onToggle} checked={checked}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just tell it is an `any` type - write `(event: any)`. Works everywhere (in `functions`, the `onClick` attribute etc...).