# Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339) Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Question is same as this:

[TypeScript: Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & Element'. Why it doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57030813/typescript-property-checked-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-element-w)

But only for different framework.

I need this answear for ANGULAR 2+ . Currently i am using angular 9

```
public CheckBoxChange(event: Event) { 
    this.service.change(this.d!.id.toString(), event.target.checked).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res
    }, err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Problem is here **event.target.checked**

Error message:

> Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)

How to fix this ? Ok i can set type: any but this is not solution.

Comment: What kind of checkbox are you using, and what kind of change event does it emit?

Comment: <input type="checkbox"
                                       [checked]="varData"
                                       (change)="CheckBoxChange($event)">

Answer (score 28):

`Event` is a rather generic class and so is `EventTarget`. At the position, you are accessing `event.target` there is no way for the TS compiler to deduce, that this `event.target` is indeed a checkbox, so it assumes it to be a generic `HTMLElement`. If you want to access properties of a checkbox, which is a `HTMLInputElement`, you have to specify the type yourself.

```
public CheckBoxChange(event: Event) { 
    const ischecked = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).checked
    this.service.change(this.d!.id.toString(), ischecked).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res
    }, err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Unfortunately now It is giving an error: `'event' is deprecated.ts(6385)`.
The more straightforward correction is to, instead of passing the event in the template, pass the target. Then in the handler, you receive `$target: EventTarget` and get the ischecked  with `const ischecked = (<HTMLInputElement>$target).checked;`